# Control Flow and Iteration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, iteration

I need to iterate through the array and multiply a number by 10 if it is greater than or equal to 5. Here is the code:

```js
const timesTenIfOverFive = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < timesTenIfOverFive.length; i++) {
  if (i >= 5) {
    console.log(timesTenIfOverFive[i] * 10);
  } else {
    console.log(timesTenIfOverFive[i]);
  }
}

console.log(timesTenIfOverFive);

// -> should print [230, 90, 110, 2, 100, 60]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access the element and change it.

```js
const timesTenIfOverFive = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];

for (let i = 0; i < timesTenIfOverFive.length; i++) {
    if(timesTenIfOverFive[i]>=5){
    timesTenIfOverFive[i]=timesTenIfOverFive[i]*10;
    }
}

console.log(timesTenIfOverFive);
```

Also since you are mutating the array, i recommend using var or let for that and not const as follows:

```js
var timesTenIfOverFive = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];
var res = timesTenIfOverFive.map(x=> x>=5?x*10:x);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your comment. But I have one more question; how could you change the value of timesTenIfOverFive when it is "const"? I think you can't change the value or data when the variable is constant. But is it possible to change the value when you put [i] right next to the variable because you are indicating the value of its array instead of the whole array itself? If you explain to me how you came up with that solution, I would appreciate it! Thanks.

Comment: Hi @user12860710, constant cannot change through re-assignment or be redeclared, as it is stated in the docs. But you can mutate it using the index. I just thought you wanted a const array thats why i used the same keyword. If that answers your question, do tick it correct.

Comment: @user12860710, there is a tick mark right beside my answer, please tick it, if my answer satisfied your question.

Answer (score -1):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new Array by *mapping* over an existing one

```js
const arr = [23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6];
const timesTenIfOverFive = arr.map(n => n>=5 ? n*10 : n );

console.log(timesTenIfOverFive)
// -> should print [230, 90, 110, 2, 100, 60]
```

In short, the `?:` Ternary Operator does :

```
n >= 5 ?    // is n greater or equal 5 ?
n * 10 :    // if true return the multiplication by 10
n           // else return the n
```

---

For a reusable function:

```js
const timesTenIfOverFive = arr => arr.map(n => n>=5 ? n*10 : n );

console.log(timesTenIfOverFive([23, 9, 11, 2, 10, 6]))
// -> should print [230, 90, 110, 2, 100, 60]
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you for showing me different ways of coding.